# List in SwiftUI is preventing to change background color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my ZStack I set color to change the background. However only color I see is changing the top safearea bar. I want the color to change behind the list but I am not able to change it. But if I delete the list from my stack, the whole background changes. So the questions is why is my list preventing me from changing the black background color?

https://imgur.com/XWSmZVY

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.pink).ignoresSafeArea()
                .border(Color.red) // Add this for debugging
            VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(dummyContents) { content in
                            contentRow(content: content)
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.green)
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
            }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func contentRow(content: WebViewContent) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Username")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                if let title = content.title {
                    Text("Dummy Title: \(title)")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .lineLimit(5)
                        .frame(height: 74)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Dummy data for testing
    var dummyContents: [WebViewContent] = [
        WebViewContent(id: UUID(), title: "Dummy Title 1", date: Date()),
        WebViewContent(id: UUID(), title: "Dummy Title 2", date: Date()),
        WebViewContent(id: UUID(), title: "Dummy Title 3", date: Date()),
    ]
}
```

Comment: This needs a [mre]

Comment: have your tried adding `.listRowBackground(Color.green)` to your `List`, eg after `.onDelete(...)`.
 Note, use `ZStack { Color(.pink).ignoresSafeArea() ...` instead of `ZStack { background(Color .pink)  ...` which does not work.

Comment: i updated the code with minimal reproducible  @jnpdx

Comment: Already tried and did not change it @workingdogsupportUkraine also added a minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, adding `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` to my list fixed it.

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```